# Working with vectors in C++

Tags: c++, stdvector

I got an assignment that I need help on. I tried to initialize a vector be be

```
vector<char> symbol(26) = {'!', '^', '&', '*', '@', '(', ')', '-', '#', '_', '=', '+', '[', '{', '$', ']', '}', ';', ':', ',', '%', '<', '.', '>', '/', '?'};
```

But I keep getting an error. What should be the the correct syntax that could function like

```
symbol.at(0) = '!';
symbol.at(1) = '^';
symbol.at(2) = '&';
```

.........

Comment: if you get an error you can surely quote that (edit your question accordingly to represent all info you have)

Comment: how can i put all the symbols into the vector?

Answer (score 4):

```
vector<char> symbol(26);
```

This declares a `vector<char>` called `symbol` and constructs it with the constructor argument `26` to create 26 `char`s.

```
vector<char> symbol = { ... };
```

This declares a `vector<char>` called `symbol` and initialises it with the elements `...`.

**You cannot, and do not need to, mix these two approaches together.**

It seems likely that you're thinking of array declaration (e.g. `char symbol[26] = { ... }`), but arrays are not vectors and vectors are not arrays… and constructor parameter lists are not array dimensions.

**Remove the `(26)`**.

---

You're also best off removing the `=` since you're using the "new" C++11 list-initialisation.

```
vector<char> symbol{'!', '^', '&', '*', '@', ... };
```